# Action of SL2 on subspaces over a finite field

Tags: group-theory, finite-fields, group-actions

Let V a vector space of dimension 2 over $\Bbb F^3$, i.e $V = \Bbb F^2_3$. We know that $SL_2(\Bbb F^3)$ acts on $\Omega = \{W \le V : \dim(W) = 1\}$. Note that $card(\Omega)= 4$.

It implies that there exists an homomorphism $$\theta : SL_2(\Bbb F^3) \longrightarrow \operatorname{Sym}(\Omega) \simeq S_4$$

$$g \longmapsto \theta (g)(x) = gx$$

Note that $\ker(\theta) = Z = \{kI_2$ with k $\in \Bbb F^3 \}$. Right now I am trying to understand the solution given to an exercice. They numbered the four elements of $\Omega$ as follow:

1 = $<(1,0)>$

2 = $<(0,1)>$

3 = $<(1,1)>$

4 = $<(1,2)>$

Then, they wrote that we can compute some images by $\theta$ :

$$\theta(\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1\\  0 & 1\\ \end{pmatrix})=(234)$$
$$\theta(\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0\\  1 & 1\\ \end{pmatrix})=(134)$$

They did not provide any steps for the computation, and I do not understand how $SL_2(\Bbb F^3)$ acts on $\Omega$. Furthermore in the next question they ask to compute the inverse of some groups $H$, $H = <(123)>, H = <(234)>, H = <(12)(34)>$:

$$\theta^{-1}((12)(34))=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1\\  0 & 1\\ \end{pmatrix}Z$$

Comment: The action is via $A \cdot \left\langle \begin{pmatrix} x\\ y\end{pmatrix} \right\rangle = \left\langle A \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix} \right\rangle$.